# Find Offset in Grid

Tags: c#, math, grid

I'm sorry about the vague title, but I'm not really sure how to ask this without being very specific. If you suggest a title which is more clear, I'll change it as soon as I can.

Anyway, I don't think I can ask my question very succinctly without first providing a little background information. In a 2D space, I am creating "acres", which contain "tiles".

[image: 64 tiles]

*[One Acre with 64 Tiles]*

For the sake of clarity, we'll assume that in this specific instance, there are 12 acres, four in the first row, four in the second, and four in the third. Each acre has 64 tiles in it, in an eight by eight grid.

[image: Twelve acres]

*[Twelve Acres, each with 64 Tiles]*

I am generating a texture the width and height of the desired number of acres, multiplied by the number of tiles in each acre (in our example, the texture would be 32 pixels wide [the number of acres in a horizontal row {4} multiplied by the number of tiles in an acre {8}], and 24 pixels tall [the number of acres in a vertical column {3} multiplied by the number of tiles in an acre {8}]). The texture is then filled with perlin noise, which I would like to use to colour each tile.

[image: perlin]

*[Single Acre, with 64 Tiles, next to the Perlin image generated for it (scaled up). This has a slight random colour variation applied to each tile.]*

I would like to generate one image for all of the acres, and read from it each time a new acre is created, but therein lies the problem, and the subject of my question. How do I get the offset, so that each adjacent acre continues the pattern?

[image: what I want]

*[What I want (to get this, I just created a single larger tile)]*

The method I'm currently using doesn't seem to work, however, and ends up creating something like the following.

[Strange Result http://2catstudios.github.io/images/StackOverflow/150113_Grid_Offset/Perlin_Twelve_Acres_NoSpace.png](http://2catstudios.github.io/images/StackOverflow/150113_Grid_Offset/Perlin_Twelve_Acres_NoSpace.png)
*[Strange Result]*

Following is the code which I'm currently using to find the (incorrect, I assume) offset. The link directs to a Gist, where the perlin generation function, and acre/tile generation functions are pasted.

```
int xOffset = ( parentAcreXIndex * desiredWidth );
int yOffset = ( parentAcreYIndex * desiredHeight );

new Color ( 0.000f, 0.502f + ( parentWorld.worldPerlin.GetPixel ( xOffset + ( desiredWidth - tileXIndex ), yOffset + ( desiredHeight - tileYIndex )).grayscale * 0.3f ), 0.000f, 1 );
```

[Full class (Links to GitHub's Gist), the above line is at 100](https://gist.github.com/AVividLight/99202693c86e0c98f3dc)

I don't really know what else to say; my mind is a bit "foggy" from trying to figure this out, so please forgive me if I've left something important out. Do let me know, and I'll update my post with the required information.

Also, I'm sorry about this question, it must be pretty hard to understand. I'm going to read over this a few times, after I publish it, to see if I can improve the wording.

Thank you for your time!
Michael

## Edit

Thank you for taking a look at this! It turns out the problem was that the plane I was using for visualization was actually upside down. I'll make sure to check simple things like that in the future, sorry for the confusion! I have left the question up, because I was given enough points here to post images, and when I tried to delete it, the points were revoked. When I earn more points, I will come back to delete this. Thanks!

Comment: Your 'strange result' image link is broken for me.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking this:

If I have a grid of pixels, which are grouped into 'acres' (32x32), how do I map from a given pixel (as the row and col of an acre) to the overall pixel?

Acres begin at every 32nd pixel, so for a given acre (acreX, acreY)

```
acreOriginInTextureX = acreX * 8;
acreOriginInTextureY = acreY * 8;
```

So a given tile (tileX, tileY) within an acre will be:

```
tilePosInTextureX = acreOriginInTextureX + tileX
                  = acreX * 8 + tileX
tilePosInTextureY = acreY * 8 + tileY
```

Really this is:

```
tilePosInTextureX = acreX * tilesPerAcreX + tileX
```

... and same for Y.

NB: I'm assuming zero indexing everywhere. If not, you'll need to subtract 1 from acreX, acreY, tileX, tileY, but *not* tilesPerAcreX or Y.

Comment: Phil H, thanks for the response! I'm sorry for writing a vague question, but I wasn't actually sure what was wrong, so I didn't know how to phrase it correctly. I have since found a solution, please see the updated section of my question for an explanation (I don't have enough characters to paste it here).